# Is 1h 45min enough layover time for connecting flight + passport control

Tags: schengen, transit, short-connections, fra

I'm looking for an upcoming trip that has me transiting in Frankfurt via Lufthansa onwards to France - it's not a major city hence the need for a transit.

The thing is, the proposed layover is 1h 45min. I would like to know if this is enough, seeing that since I'm not from the EU, I have to clear passport control in Frankfurt before going for the connection. Or would it be better for a slightly longer one of 3 hours at Zurich airport (via Swiss Air)?

Answer (score 3):

1. You haven't told us where your flight originates.  If you're from the USA, remember that most of the world is not the USA.
2. Frankfurt is a very efficient airport indeed, so you'd probably just about do it **IF** your baggage has been checked through to your final destination, but whether that's likely to be done is something you would have to ascertain from Lufthansa.
3. Personally, I would not be satisfied with less than 2 hours between flights -- you've got to allow for potential delay in the arrival of your incoming flight and queues at security.
4. I've no experience of Zurich airport, though the Swiss are normally hyper-efficient.  3 hours is a much more comfortable gap between flights since security checks seem to have been intesified everywhere over the past year or so..

Answer (score 3):

Unless passport control at FRA is understaffed and there are several wide-body arrivals at the time of your arrival, it should be OK in my experience.

If you miss it, though, you'll be booked onto the next available connection for free, provided the trip is in a single booking.

Comment: True, with the caveat that it's usually the "next available connection _with the same airline_". They will sometimes rebook you with other airlines when it suits _their_ needs, but it's not something you can insist on yourself. So part of the decision will hinge on how soon that particular airline has another flight from Frankfurt to the destination in question.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Lufthansa and Swiss are part of the same group, and both have frequent flights to Zurich

Comment: We don't know what the OP's eventual destination is, except that it's a non-major city in France. I don't think we should assume that every French airport has lots of Lufthansa/Swiss flights from both Frankfurt and Zürich.